# Is there a way to fetch all of my tweets and save them on my computer?

Tags: twitter, twitter-api

The place I work at had a big convention last year in December (2010) and we heavily promoted participants to use twitter to interact online. Now I am trying to go back and see if I can fetch all the tweets that used the convention hashtag and possibly save a copy locally. I did twitter search but it does not go as far back to see the tweets.

Is there a way to search this far back in Twitter?

Comment: Just as a note, [this is yet another ifttt way](https://ifttt.com/recipes/148812-all-your-tweets-in-a-google-spreadsheet) I backup my tweets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following applications are able to save all your tweets to your computer:

- [**MKTwitter**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mktwitter/) is a nice free, open source application which lets you connect to your Twitter account and save your Tweets to your computer. No hassle, no knowledge required. Just download it, run it and you are done.
- [**Tweetake**](http://tweetake.com/) is another website which connect to your Twitter account. The website is rather barebone but the way it works is really …great! In fact, thanks to it you will be able to save all your Twitter details and  information. Its options let you backup the following things: Followers, Friends, Favorites, Your Tweets, Everything! As a result, the website will return you with a CVS file which you can open using Office Excel.
- [**TwitterBackup**](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/java/backup-twitter-tweets-with-twitterbackup.html) is a free javascript application. Again, thanks to it you will be able to backup all your Twitter account. The nice thing about this application is that everything will be saved in a XML file which is completely compatible with Office Excel.
- [**TweetBackup**](http://tweetbackup.com/) is a web utility which, as its name suggests, is able to save your Tweets somewhere else. Other features include: daily backups, friend list backup,  no installation required, very easy to understand, very easy User Interface, set-it and forget about it procedure.

[image]

Comment: @Stealth: You're welcome. By the way, you can check the tick mark next to my answer to set it as accepted answer.

Comment: Did that! :-)